# What is "Transformation of Functions by Substitution"?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In [**Introduction to Analysis of the Infinite**](https://books.google.ru/books/about/Introduction_to_Analysis_of_the_Infinite.html?id=se3UBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Leonhard Euler **Transformation of Functions by Substitution** introduced this way:

> 46. If *y* is some function of *z*, and *z* is defined by a new variable *x*, then *y* can also be defined by *x*.
>       Since previously *y* was a function of *z*, now a new variable quantity *x* is introduced by which both the *y* and the *z* can be defined. Thus, if [image], we let [image]. When this value is substituted for *z*, [image].

How such arbitrary substitutions can be even legal? What principles let you come out with specific substitutions?

Example #2:

> [image] ... we let [image] ... thus ... [image] ... so ... z becomes [image]

How can you arbitrary say that [image] ? How can you know that such function even exists?

Example #3:

> [image] ... let [image] so that [image] and hence [image]. It follows that [image] and [image]

Example #4:

> [image] ... let [image] ... then [image]

How the second step is even legal?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with those latter quotes. The first says that if you have $y(z)$ and $z(x)$ then we can consider $y(z(x))$ so both $y$ and $z$ are functions of $x$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thank you for your comment. I edited **example #2** to clarify my question about arbitrary introducing new functions.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I want to clarify on that Euler doesn't state you have *y(z)* and *z(x)* originally, but you can introduce a variable *x* so that *z(x)* will help you modify *y(z)* so that *y(x)*. Euler motivates it for reasons like getting rid of irrationality or radicals, but I wonder how it's even possible to arbitrary introduce such values.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen added **example #4** from the book (&50) where Euler obviously introduces new variable out of his head to make y and z being expressed without radicals.